# Como retornar um objeto literal num arrow function?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Quanto tento retornar um objeto literal com `Arrow Function`, dá um erro:

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3].map( i => {valor: i, data: new Date() })
```

Como contornar isso no Javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode colocar o objecto entre parêntesis.

Assim:

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3].map( i => ({valor: i, data: new Date()}))

console.log(items)
```

Comment: WOW! ótima maneira de driblar o parser do JS, kkkkk

Comment: Mt legal! [Tem nesta documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals). 

Answer (score 4):

Esse erro se dá porque o JS não atribui valor à uma variável usando dois-pontos (`:`), que é o que se está tentando fazer dentro da função.

Usando `.map` me parece que você quer retornar uma array de objetos à partir da array mapeada, logo você pode usar um `return` com os valores dento de chaves `{}` devido às outras chaves delimitarem o corpo da função:

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3].map( i => { return {valor: i, data: new Date()} })
console.log(items)
```

Comment: Dá pra mandar um `i => Object.create({ ... })` também, mas dá tristeza só de pensar, kkkk

Comment: Pois eh rsrs 